# Complex Collision Boxes

Tags: collision

I'm trying to get a ball to go through in between the cup gear things shown in the screenshot below.

It seems that the collision box does not consider the cups. Yes, the ball fits and they are rotating in the right direction.

If there is already an answer to this, please link it.

[image: image1] [image: image2(active simulation)] [image: image3]

If you have any questions about what is going on/ what the project is, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the collision type for your wheels/cups objects from *Convex Hull* Into *Mesh*, otherwise only the physics system will only interpret it as if it was covered in tape.

[image]

This of course will be at the expense of performance, more complex bounds types are slower to calculate, so you should always use the simplest bounds type that will yield an acceptable result.