# Bottles with balls inside - PHYSIC SIMULATION

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

I want to create in blender a realistic physic simulation with bottles that have balls inside, first example is created Blender and the second in another 3D software. How to create this simulation in blender? I have to checked the normals, applied all transforms for scale, position and rotation, set Origin > origin to geometry, increasing the Steps per second and Solver Iterations in the Rigid Body World settings (I tried with the maxima 1000 and 100), set collision shape to Mesh and tried 0.4 or 0 as margins and source to final, but doesn't work..., the simulation is a mess...

I have attached here the blend file, Who can help me how to configure the rigid body settings to achieve a realistic result similar with the second example ?

Here it is my blend file:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hFKMqcwAECv01WKFnYMo5G4z8hgmvUSz
[image: blender]
[image: cinema 4d]

Who can help me... ?

Comment: Which part are you having difficulties with?

Comment: Hard to know what is _"realistic"_ without dropping and filming bottles.  In example above, as I see it suggest dropping balls before bottles.

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139594/complex-collision-boxes/